# Why no Spring Project in File > New?

Tags: eclipse, spring

I installed Spring Tool Suite(STS) for Eclipse to eclipse 3.7 and the installation was successful.
Unfortunately,
there is no Spring Project option in the Menu File->New;
only a Spring Roo Project option in the Menu File->New->Other.
How can I create a Spring Template Project?
Do I have to install Spring IDE again?

Answer (score 4):

file > new > "Spring Project" is not there with 3.7.2; in order to see Spring Templates I did the following selections:

- File > New > Spring Legacy Project
  or
- File > New > Project > Spring Legacy Project

Both gives you all the Spring Templates:

```
                          Simple Projects
                          - Simple Java
                          - Simple Java Maven
                          - Simple Java Web Maven
                          - ....
                          - ....
                          - Spring MVC Project
```

Answer (score 1):

Not require.
There are two options you can use sts tool.

1. You can use STS (**Spring Tool Suite**) tool plugin in eclipse
2. You can directly download STS tool from https://spring.io/tools/sts/all

In both the options it will give you the option to select the new Spring project what ever based on your requirment.

Comment: But I couldn't find Spring Project in New menu, Why?